# How to add new layout in menu item?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I can see there's an option to choose a layout:

[image]

How can I add new custom layout with template override?

I have tried several way for eg. `html/layouts/mylayout.php`, `html/com_content/category/default_mylayout.php`. But none is working. So, how should I do?

Answer (score 1):

With that "Choose a Layout" option in a menu item of type "Category Blog" you can specify **what article layout** to use **for the individual articles from that category blog** when you visit them individually.

Add your article layout file `default_mylayout.php` + the xml file `default_mylayout.xml` to  the folder: `/templates/your-template/html/com_content/article/`.

After that the article layout for the individual category blog articles should be available in that "Choose a Layout" dropdown selection.

Comment: This is correct if you want to choose the article layout.  If you want to change the blog layout then you need to either do an override or a new menu item like @Arlen has shown.  Effectively the same as @pe7er but instead of the menu structure ending in article you use `templates/your-template/html/com_content/category/`.  Don't forget to use the XML which you can copy from `components/com_content/category/default.xml` then when you add a new menu item you will see your menu item is also there.

Comment: I see the suggestion here and in the docs to "add the XML" but no pointer to what the XML should look like. In my current install of Joomla, there is not a default.xml file to copy. Any more pointers?

Comment: OK, more searches and might be the wrong path in the comment `components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/default.xml` is the one to copy?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a xml file along with the php file.

Check out the docs :
https://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla

Comment: the link din't help me

Comment: Please try to rename your files. mylayout.php to mylayout_blog.php  mylayout_blog.xml

Comment: not working....

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem. From the first screenshot up there it looks like you're looking to set a layout on a menu item type "Articles - Category Blog"

The problem is, that's *already* a layout. You can't stuff two values in the layout parameter. The only thing you can really choose in that particular case is whether to use the template override for the category blog layout (template/html/com_content/article/blog.php) or the original, or one in one of the other templates (essentially selecting whether the layout will be "blog" or "templatename:blog").

If what you're looking to do is create a new layout that's kinda/sorta the blog, you have to create it as a menu item in its own right. But you'll still run into an issue. The com_content component's category view code is hard-coded to do certain things when the layout is 'blog' that will not get done for any other layout. (Yes it was a Bad Idea to do that. It was jaw-droppingly, mind-bendingly bad, in fact. But apparently no one was about to let a silly thing like excessively tight coupling stop them from implementing it.)

So again, if your goal is to create a layout using the data for the category blog layout, you either have to do a template override of that core layout or consign yourself to essentially writing -- and maintaining -- a portion of the view in your template code.